# local folder files not taking, taking only core files (magento)

Tags: magento

i wanted to change the catalogsearch result file so i created a catalogsearch folder in the "code\local\mage" folder but the changes made here are not being seen at all the program directly checks into the "code\core\mage" folder, i am very confused why it is only taking the files of the core files only and not taking the files on the local folder ,

any help could be very much appreciated , :)

Comment: You may have better luck on responses if you accept answers for more than 6 of the 45+ questions you've asked.

Comment: List out the full path of the file you want to replace from app/code/core and the full path of the new file you created in app/code/local.  Also, explain your evidence for the file not taking. Both of these will help other people troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

/code/local/mage will not do, as the names are case sensitive. You need to preserve the exact directory names through all the directory structure (e.g. /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php).